# CodeIgniter 4 save method not working - data not being saved to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, model-view-controller, codeigniter-4

Tried to use Save method in codeigniter 4 as per in the documentation and was using models to save data to the db but it did not save any data to the database .what might be the problem someone help me please?

This is the controller function I wrote y logic like this:
`  public function save(int $expense_id = -1)
{
$request = \Config\Services::request();

```
    $expense_data = [
        'category' => $this->request->getPost('category'),
        'description' => $this->request->getPost('description'),
        'amount' => $this->request->getPost('amount'),
        'added_by' => $this->request->getPost('added_by'),
        'createdAt'=>date('Y-m-d'), strtotime($request->getPost('createdAt')),
    ];

    // transactional to make sure that everything is working well
    $this->db->transStart();

    if ($this->_expenseModel->save($expense_data, $expense_id))
    {
        //New Payment
        if ($expense_id == -1)
        {
            return $this->response->setJSON([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Expense added successfully',
                'expense_id' => $expense_data['expense_id']
            ]);
        }
        else //previous loan
        {
            return $this->response->setJSON([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Expense updated successfully',
                'expense_id' => $expense_id
            ]);
        }
    }
    else
    //failure
    {
        return $this->response->setJSON([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Failed! Error while updating expense',
            'expense_id' => -1
        ]);
    }
    $this->db->transComplete();
}
```

And this is my Model:

Comment: Please post your model. My guess is that you are missing entries in the `$allowdFields`-array.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.